# 読み取られ without る

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

> **示に従い、カメラで学生証を写すと顔写真や学籍番号などが読み取られログインが進む。**

The school released a new application, and the teacher instructed the students to install it on their cell phones. The activation process is by reading (scanning) the students' ID card with the camera on their cell phones. This sentence is the story of the main character who tried to activate the application.

Generally, I understand the meaning of each words, but I'm at lost on how to put it into a sentence in a proper order.

**示に従い、カメラで学生証を写すと顔写真や学籍番号などが...**

"...my face shot and student registration number and so on, when I photographed my student ID card with the camera according to the instructions."

But I'm confused with this part of the sentence: **...読み取られログインが進む。**

**読み取られ** --> **読み取られる**, I'm guessing that the **る** was excluded to insert a conjunction. I have seen several sentences with the same case, so I would like to ask if there is any rules/references related to it.

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Comment: `示に従い` <-- **指**示に従い ？

Comment: @Chocolate - Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm confused with this part of the sentence: ...読み取られログインが進む。

It's the formal version of continuative 読み取られて, dropping the て and using the 連用形【れんようけい】 instead.